# Ember.js: live update is not working for #each binding to a subset of store records

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm having trouble making live update work for a {{#each}} helper with binding to a subset of store records, so the data used in the loop is retrieved like this:

```
this.store.find('datainfo', {relId: 1})
```

And every time I add a new `datainfo`, no update for items displayed by the loop.
If I remove the query parameter, this works properly.

Here is a JSbin to illustrate the situation: http://jsbin.com/megohu/13/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find detailed explanation for this behavior there: http://emberjs.com/guides/models/frequently-asked-questions/#toc_how-do-i-inform-ember-data-about-new-records-created-on-the-backend

In short, auto updated properties must return result of `this.store.filter` or `this.store.all` instead of `this.store.findQuery`.

One of the way is fetch all `this.store.findQuery` in model hook of Em.Route and then return `this.store.filter` with filter function.

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/pewope/1/edit?js,output).